# Type Inference by hand

Tags: types, scheme, type-inference

I've got a test tomorrow, and one of the topics we're covering is type inference.  I'm reviewing an assignment we did, along with the answers we were given for it.  However, I can't seem to follow.  A question that I can't seem to connect the answer to is for this function:

```
(define foo (lambda (f x y) ((f x) y)))
```

Now to do the type inferencing, first, create types:

```
f : 'f  
x : 'x  
y : 'y  
return = 'r
```

Then you do the constraints.  Looking at the first chunk where you send `x` into `f` gives:

```
'f = 'x -> 'w (w being a new type representing the result of that function).
```

To include the y now (`z` being another new type with the result of the function `w`):

```
'w = 'y -> 'z
```

This would therefore make `'r = 'z` (`'z` is what would be returned). Lastly, where I'm confused about, is where it's all put together.  To me, it would become:

```
val foo = fn: 'x -> 'w -> 'z
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
val foo = fn: 'x -> ('y -> 'z) -> 'z
```

However, the answer given includes two more types (`'x` and `'y`):

```
val foo = fn: 'x -> ('y -> 'z) * 'x * 'y -> 'z
```

Can someone explain to me why those are added, and when to use `*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed solution:

```
val foo = fn: 'x -> ('y -> 'z) -> 'z
```

would make `foo` be a function that takes a single argument of type `'x` and returns a function that takes a single argument of type `('y -> 'z)` and returns a value of type `'z`.  But you can't call with `foo` with just one argument, so it's clearly not a function of one argument.  It needs to be a function of three arguments.  Let's take a closer look at the actual solution.  The solution,

```
val foo = fn: 'x -> ('y -> 'z) * 'x  * 'y  -> 'z
              ----------------   ---   ---    -----------
                    1st          2nd   3rd    result type
```

says that `foo` is a function that takes three arguments.  The first argument has type

```
'x -> ('y -> 'z)
```

which means that it's a function that takes an `'x` and returns a

```
'y -> 'z
```

which is a function that takes a `'y` and returns a `'z`. That first argument is the function `f` and, as you described, it has to be able to take `x` as an argument, and return a (function that can take `y` as an argument and return a `'z`).  Now that's just the *first* argument of `foo`.  `foo` takes three arguments.  The second is `x`, which has type `'x`, and the third is `y`, which has type `'y`.  The `*` in the type of `foo` is separating the types of the arguments:

```
val foo = fn: 'x -> ('y -> 'z) * 'x * 'y -> 'z.
              ----------------   --   --
                    f             x    y
```

Comment: honestly... of all the questions I've asked, I think yours is the best response I've seen (not that the others haven't been good). So thanks a ton!  I didn't realize there was a separate little section in the answer for each argument.